# How to compile Pro*C file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I installed Visual Studio 2010 recently, and migrated my project from Visual Studio 2005 to 2010. After migration, I can't compile Pro*C files in my project. I use the Oracle 10g precomplier. I get this error message:

```
Syntax error at line 48, column 9, file C:\VisualStudio10\VC\include\vadefs.h: typedef _W64 unsigned int uintptr_t;
PCC-S-02201, Encoutered the symbol "__w64" when expecting one of the following:
auto, char, const, double, enum .......... a typedef name
```

My project complied in VS 2005 correctly. What's the matter on VS 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pro*c in detail, but you probably should read this page from the MS doku:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s04b5w00.aspx

Since the symbol __w64 is only for some 32->64 portability warnings, it may be sufficient to define this symbol empty. Place a `#define __w64` in a central place or add  the empty symbol definition for `__w64` into your project's compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the code and it seemed to resolve it.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    /* This allows compilation on vs 2010 */ 
    #define _W64
#endif
```